# JSF h:selectOneMenu with ajax gets an sql exception

Tags: sql, ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

I can fill the selectOneMenu with correct data and dataTable can show the first 
selected item correctly. But whenever I switch the combobox items, I get an sql 
exception like that  serverError: class java.sql.SQLException Invalid cursor 
position.

Here is my result.xhtml

```
    <h:form>          
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.choice}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.namesForMenu}"/>  
            <f:ajax event="change" render="result"/>

        </h:selectOneMenu> 
     <h:dataTable  id="result" value="#{productBean.showResult()}" 
       var="item"
                border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="productName">Product Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText  value="#{item.product_name}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="productPrice">Product Price</f:facet>
                <h:outputText  value="#{item.product_price}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="productDiscount">Product Discount</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.product_discount}"/>
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Here is my ProductBean.java

```
public ResultSet showResult() throws SQLException {

    if (dataSource == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");
    }

    connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");
    }
    try {           
        if (choice != null) {

           PreparedStatement getAddresses = connection.prepareStatement(
                 "SELECT product_name, product_price, product_discount"
             +" FROM product WHERE product_name = "+"'"+getChoice()+"'");
            CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
            rowSet.populate(getAddresses.executeQuery());
            return rowSet;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } 
    finally {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```